# java.util.Locale does not recognize Austria

Tags: java, locale

Would need on identifying what is the locale id for `Austria`. I have tried with `de_AT`/`at`/`at_at` as mentioned [here](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/de-AT/)

But it seems Locale API doesn't recognize these locale, any pointers..?

Exception when trying with `de_AT`:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Couldn't find 3-letter language code for de_at
    at java.util.Locale.getISO3Language(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.rupesh.CQInstanceHelper.language(Main.java:74)
    at com.test.rupesh.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

Comment: have you tried "de-AT"?

Comment: yes, even this is also resulting in same exception.

Comment: deu or AUT?? Because it says, 3-letter language code missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying with de_AT exactly?

```
Locale austria = new Locale("de", "AT");
System.out.println("Locale=" + austria);
System.out.println("ISO3 language=" + austria.getISO3Language());
```

prints out:

```
Locale=de_AT
ISO3 language=deu
```

EDIT: Do not instantiate locales this way:

```
Locale austria = new Locale("de_AT");
System.out.println("Locale=" + austria);
System.out.println("ISO3 language=" + austria.getISO3Language());
```

prints out:

```
Locale=de_at
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Couldn't find 3-letter language code for de_at
    at java.util.Locale.getISO3Language(Locale.java:568)
    at Scribble.main(Test.java:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

check the available locations using this

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
```